Entity Framework: could not create socket for "db_connection": listen unix /tmp/cloudsql-proxy-tmp/db_connection/.s.PGSQL.5432: bind: invalid argument
I'm using Google Cloud Run to host a .Net Core 8 application using the Google Cloud Functions Framework. THe entity framework version is 8.0.7. The PostgreSQL database is hosted on Google Cloud SQL. The Cloud Run deployment has the cloud SQL connections configuration in GCP.
The connection string:
var connectionString = new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder
{
    SslMode = SslMode.Disable, // Even though the sslmode parameter is set to disable, the Cloud SQL Auth Proxy does provide an encrypted connection.
    Host = $"/cloudsql/{environmentVariableService.DatabaseConnectionName}",
    Username = environmentVariableService.DatabaseUser,
    Password = environmentVariableService.DatabasePassword,
    Database = environmentVariableService.DatabaseName,
    Pooling = true,
    ApplicationName = environmentVariableService.FunctionTarget,
    MinPoolSize = 60,
    CommandTimeout = 30,
    Port = 5432
};

services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
    options =>
        options.UseNpgsql(connectionString.ConnectionString), ServiceLifetime.Transient);

I'm getting the following error multiple times each day, but most of the time I'm not getting it. It happens when using the ApplicationDbContext injected in a service to access the database.
public DocumentInfoRepository(ApplicationDbContext dbContext, RequestCancellationBase requestCancellationBase)
{
    _dbContext = dbContext;
    _requestCancellationBase = requestCancellationBase;
}

public async Task<DBModel.DocumentInfo> GetDocumentById(Guid id)
{
    // I get the error on the following line ⬇️
    return await _dbContext.DocumentInfos.SingleOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == id, _requestCancellationBase);
}

I have to redeploy my cloud-run container to make it stop for a while. My questions: Why am I getting this error? What must I change to stop getting this error?
could not create socket for "db_connection": listen unix /tmp/cloudsql-proxy-tmp/db_connection/.s.PGSQL.5432: bind: invalid argument

    An unexpected error occured.
    System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure.
     ---> Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Failed to connect to /cloudsql/environment-production:northamerica-northeast1:postgres-database-name/.s.PGSQL.5432
     ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (99): Cannot assign requested address
       at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.CreateException(SocketError error, Boolean forAsyncThrow)
       at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ConnectAsync(Socket socket)
       at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ConnectAsync(EndPoint remoteEP, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass220_0.<ConnectAsync>g__ConnectAsync|2(CancellationToken ct)
       at Npgsql.TaskTimeoutAndCancellation.ExecuteAsync(Func`2 getTaskFunc, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
       at Npgsql.TaskTimeoutAndCancellation.ExecuteAsync(Func`2 getTaskFunc, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<ConnectAsync>g__OpenSocketConnectionAsync|220_1(Socket socket, EndPoint endpoint, NpgsqlTimeout perIpTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.ConnectAsync(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
       at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.ConnectAsync(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
       at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
       at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<Open>g__OpenCore|213_1(NpgsqlConnector conn, SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
       at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<Open>g__OpenCore|213_1(NpgsqlConnector conn, SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
       at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
       at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Npgsql.PoolingDataSource.OpenNewConnector(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
       at Npgsql.PoolingDataSource.OpenNewConnector(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Npgsql.PoolingDataSource.<Get>g__RentAsync|34_0(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
       at Npgsql.PoolingDataSource.<Get>g__RentAsync|34_0(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Npgsql.PoolingDataSource.Get(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<Open>g__OpenAsync|42_0(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<Open>g__OpenAsync|42_0(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.<>c.<MoveNextAsync>b__20_0(DbContext _, AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
       at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
       at lambda_method124(Closure, QueryContext)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ExecuteAsync[TSource,TResult](MethodInfo operatorMethodInfo, IQueryable`1 source, Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ExecuteAsync[TSource,TResult](MethodInfo operatorMethodInfo, IQueryable`1 source, LambdaExpression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Function.Repositories.DocumentInfo.DocumentInfoRepository.GetDocumentById(Guid id) in /app/Repositories/DocumentInfo/DocumentInfoRepository.cs:line 36
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
       at ...


Who knows, maybe too many opened connections. Try from making ServiceLifetime.Scoped if you do not need to create DbContext on each injection.

In the OS Headers it lists this Hex 0x80004005 Error as an Access_Denied. For something like this, telling you its a Transient error and you saying it happens intermittently I'd use the .Net Polly - a resilience and transient-fault-handling library.

I already tried using ServiceLifetime.Scoped but I'm still getting the error

I found the solution. When deploying my Cloud Run service, I used Default as the execution environment. When using Default, Cloud Run was running First generation most of the time, but sometimes Second generation. When my Cloud Run service got more requests, Cloud Run switched to Second generation. As soon as I used Second generation, I got the error. Selecting First generation solved the problem.

